# Why is there a hard line in my y-axis gradient following a curve?

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves, shader-nodes

I'd really appreciate any help or insight here. I've been messing with this for hours and can't figure out how to wrap my gradient around the y-axis seamlessly. No matter what, there's a hard line at one end of the gradient (shown in the picture).

[image]

Comment: go white to orange in the center and back to white on the color ramp

Comment: Allen, here's what that looks like (same issue with the hard line): https://www.dropbox.com/s/snesfloydt71b8w/Screen%20Shot%202022-01-11%20at%204.20.15%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Ah I see, let me look again

Comment: UV coordinates mean that there will always be a seam, the best you can do is hide it when using procedural textures, or use a custom 'seamless' texture

Comment: Thanks Allen—makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cover the jump from V=`0` to V=`1`, you have to map V to some function of V whose value is the same at V=`0` and V=`1`, and (maybe) approaches that value smoothly from both sides.

Here are 2 examples.. one using a Color-Ramp, and another, mapping V's (`0`-`1`) value to (`-pi` - `pi`), and then taking `0.5*cos(the result)+0.5`.

[image]

The second one could be used as a 0-1 mix-factor to blend anything you like smoothly around the curve.

Comment: Thanks for helping Robin. I probably shouldn't be wasting anyone's time because I'm so new to this, but now I'm running into a different problem. I set up my nodes the way you suggested, but now none of the lights in my scene will work on my bezier curve. Here's a screen shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eij7h80vva96z3u/Screen%20Shot%202022-01-11%20at%205.02.16%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi @stewartmh!.. my apologies for using 'shorthand' in my illustration, to keep it small. You have plugged the color straight into the material output, which, in EEVEE, produces a flat (shadeless) material, and in Cycles, makes an emissive material. To get the surface _respond_ to light, there must be a shader in the pipeline. e.g.... use the color you have produced as the  Base Color of a Principled Shader, and plug _that_ into the material output.

Comment: That's super helpful—thank you for explaining that to me! Appreciate your help.